# Why does PHP assigns context to a static method call and does not give an E_STRICT notice?

Tags: php, methods, static, parent, strict

I ran into some very strange behaviour on PHP5.4 (also present in 5.5). Basically, I am calling a non-static method statically and I am not getting an E_STRICT error where I definitely should be getting one.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
class A
{
    public function iAmNotStatic() {}
}
```

Now, if I do this:

```
A::iAmNotStatic();
```

Then I get the error as expected `Strict standards: Non-static method A::iAmNotStatic() should not be called statically`.

And also, if I make the call from object context, I also get the same error (as expected)

```
class B 
{
    public function __construct() {
        A::iAmNotStatic();
    }
}

$b = new B(); // error here, as expected
```

However, if I do this (assign A to be the parent of B):

```
class B extends A
{
    public function __construct() {
        A::iAmNotStatic();
    }
}

$b = new B(); // no error
```

Then PHP decides that "no problem, I have an object ($b) with the same parent class (A), let's just make it the context for `iAmNotStatic`".

So, is this a feature or a bug and what might be the purpose of this confusing (undocumented?) behaviour? 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first case, you have no object context since you're calling your non-static method from outer space. But in second case, you *have* object context since `$this` will refer to instance of `B` - and, therefore, PHP will find that object context exists, and, therefore, it is a non-static call of non-static method (everything is ok). If you're hesitating about call via `::` - then, I think, you should remind that, for example,  `parent::method()`  is a valid call. I.e. referring way is not the problem here.

To be more specific:

```
class A
{
   public function foo()
   {
      echo('foo called, class: '. get_class($this).PHP_EOL);
   }
}

class B extends A
{
   public function __construct()
   {
      A::foo();
   }
}

$b=new B(); //foo called, class: B
```

so you'll see class `B` as expected since `foo()` was inherited.

Comment: Okay, so basically if I'm in an object context, I can call anything from any object of the same class context (even private methods) and make static calls to non-static methods, overriding the context the method assumes.

I wonder if this is documented somewhere? I could not find anything from the php.net documentation.